# Getting a negative number when calculating time in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I'm working on a pdf form and trying to calculate hours from 2 fields. As long as the time does not go past midnight (in 24-hour format), I get the correct response. Once it goes past midnight, I get a negative number. Is there a way to add 24 hours to the returned value if it gives a negative number?

Here's what the field is being calculated as

```js
    var startTime = this.getField("SHIFT STARTRow1").value;
    var endTime = this.getField("SHIFT ENDRow1").value;

    this.getField("TOTAL HOURSRow1").value = timeDiff(startTime, endTime);

    if ((event.value == "") || (event.value == Infinity) || isNaN(event.value)) {event.value = "";}
```

And here is the form javascript - timeDiff

```js
function timeDiff(startTime, endTime) {
    var startArr = startTime.split(":");
    var endArr = endTime.split(":");
    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, startArr[0], startArr[1], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, endArr[0], endArr[1], 0);
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var hours = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    return hours.toFixed(2)
    }

    console.log(timeDiff('6:24', '8:13')) // 1.82
```

So using this script, if I type in 12:30 as the start time and 01:45 as the end time, I get a return of -10.75. However, I need a return of 13.25.
I attempted to find another thread that helped me with this, but maybe I overlooked it. Any help?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwPeS.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If end hour is less than start, add 24

```js
function timeDiff(startTime, endTime) {
    var startArr = startTime.split(":").map(Number);
    var endArr = endTime.split(":").map(Number);
    if (startArr[0] > endArr[0]) {
      endArr[0] += 24;
    }
    var hours = endArr[0] + endArr[1]/60 - startArr[0] - startArr[1]/60;
    return hours.toFixed(2)
    }

    console.log(timeDiff('23:10', '1:00'))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to add 24 hours to the returned value if it gives a negative number?

Well, yes –

```
if(hours < 0) hours += 24;
```